# Optimize complex layout

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I develop an audio player for Android  and in my browse album activity I have a performance problem: lot of lag on scroll.

In this image is my layout representation :[image]

It's a ListView which display a row; a row contains 5 albums grouped by artist.

Each different color is a different layout file. And each file is managed by an Adapter.

In the album (orange color), I don't use compoundDrawable on the TextView because I have  ImageView lazy loading and I  don't understand how I can make this lazy loading on textview compoundDrawable.

If you need, I can post all layout files.

Comment: How can this fit onto a tiny smartphone-screen?! Perhaps you should see your performance problem as a hint that your layout is just too complex.

Comment: it's for a tablet  and imageView as 80dp square size. on a tablet 7" screen  i saw 2 rows of 5 albums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many optimizations, i change my layout like this

[image: My New Layout]

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this article?

[Android Performance Case Study](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/)

It may help in your case but not knowing more about how you are setting up the view, it's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure, if this is possible in your case easily, but I think if you make each table row a RelativeLayout, you could probably remove most or all of the LinearLayout elements for the rows. You only would have to state, that each LinearLayout in a row has to be to the left/the right of another one with android:layout_toLeftOf and android:layout_alignParentRight.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to simplify your layout in order to improve performance you will have to sacrifice something, such a simplification will not come for free.
I'd think the most promising approach would be to replace your row listview layout with a GridLayout. In principle you could handle all the layout inside that row with one such GridLayout, but in order to have a real benefit you'd have to give up the GridView (album grid by artist) and handle that as part of the GridLayout. This would probably take some extra Java code but I think that it should improve performance.